# Disable Site Collection Quotas & Locking Entirely

Tags: 2010, central-administration, site-settings, site-usage, quota

We have our SP 2010 site collection configured with the following quota template settings:

- Unchecked: Limit site storage
- Unchecked: Send warning email when site storage reaches...
- Sandboxed Solutions Resources Quota: 999999 points
- Unchecked: Send warning email when usages per day...

Even with these settings in place, every Monday, the storage quota seems to be "met" and SharePoint automatically locks the site collection (making it read-only). So we go in and unlock it, and we're good for another week.

We have basically zero physical storage limitations, both on the database and filesystem side.

I looked in the Storage Metrics section of Site Settings for the top-level site collection, and I can see the sub-sites that are using "a lot" of storage (one uses 1.8GB, the other about 1GB). The "% of Site Quota" column reads "Not Available" for all rows in this report.

We have no need for quotas and we absolutely do not want this locking to keep happening. Is there a way to stop it?

**EDIT:**

Was not actually the quota locking the site -- see comments below accepted answer.

Comment: How you know that storage quota met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is storage quota is doing this rather something else.

- if site collection met its storage quota then it will not allow any operation on the site rather lock it
- you are not seeing the value in that storage column because your quota is not set for the site collection.

I would check uls logs, IIS logs and get the clue which task is doing this.

- do you have any custom timer job or solution or any kind of policy which put the sites in locking mode? Check it
- another thing set the quota of site collection higher than the actual. I.e. If current storage is 5 GB then set it 15gb and test it.

Comment: Waqas, I believe you are correct. I just checked and our site collection backup from last night is still running. We did not have the "NoSiteLock" parameter set, so I guess it set the site collection to read-only? Is there a way to know why a site collection backup was interrupted/paused/hung?

Comment: You have to check the backup log file, uls and event log during that time frame...it is little hard but u can do it

Comment: Just confirmed that the user who reported the site collection read-only issue did not actually get a "site quota exceeded" error message, so it wasn't actually quota triggering the lock.